# Принимать GET-параметры и делать Ajax-запрос

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

У меня есть файл `conrete.php`, в котором, в зависимости от выбранного `<option>`, выводятся соответствующие данные по Ajax-запросу (отдельный скрипт).

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы `concrete.php` мог принимать GET-параметры и выводить соответствующие данные, *не используя `<form>` и не перезагружая страницу*?

К примеру, мой Ajax-запрос принимает один параметр - `id`. Как я могу сделать запрос с этим параметром, введя в адресной строке `concrete.php?id=2`?

**Примечание**: В случае, если выбрал `<option>`, то добавлять к текущему `URL` параметры.

```
/**
 * concrete.php file
 */

<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 select">
    <select class="form-control">'
        <option selected value="default">Выберите событие</option>

        <?outputEventData("event");?> // вывод <option>-ов
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 danger-events"></div> // сюда выгружаются ajax-данные

<script>

$('select.form-control').on('change', function() {
    var id = $('.form-control option:selected').val();

    if(id !== 'default') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getData.php",
            data: {id: id},
            success: function(data) {
                $('.danger-events').html(data);
            }
        });
    } 
});

</script>
```

---

```
/**
 * getData.php file
 */

<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo someData;
}
```

Comment: Конечно можно, а в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: @programmer403 не могу прийти к решению. Дайте какую-нибудь наводку, куда копать?

Comment: @phen0men , т.е. вы хотите, чтобы данные обновлялись на странице по мере ввода в адресную строку?

Comment: @br3t Когда находишься на странице, данные выводятся по выбору `<option>` через ajax-запрос. Когда просто переходишь по прямой ссылке вида `concrete.php?id=2`, данные выводятся через ajax (?)  по этому id.

Comment: @phen0men , решение из ответа вам подходит?

Comment: @phen0men, вы в курсе что ajax это технология javascript а когда вы переходите по ссылке concrete.php?id=2 вы выполняете php-скрипт это нельзя назвать что данные выводятся через ajax. Идя дальше как я понял вы хотите чтобы все данные загружались только через javascript (ajax) когда вы переходите по ссылке, и на самой странице при изменении селекта?

Comment: @programmer403 но вопрос был не только в передаче get-параметров в скрипт по ссылке..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В теории должно работать как-то так:

```
/**
 * concrete.php file
 */
...
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 danger-events">
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
            include('getData.php?inline=1&id='.$_GET['id']);
        }
    ?>
</div>
<script>

$('select.form-control').on('change', function() {
    var id = $('.form-control option:selected').val();
    history.pushState({id: id}, "", "concrete.php?id=" + id);
...

/**
 * getData.php file
 */

<?php
if(!isset($_GET['inline'])) {
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
}


if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo someData;
}
```

Comment: тс пишет не перезагружая страницу и в тоже время пишет введя в адресную строку concrete.php?id=2 ???

Comment: Т.е. нужно вызвать `concrete.php` c параметром, не вызывая файл?

Comment: Идеально. То, что и было нужно. Благодарю

Comment: Боже мой, только не используйте это в продакшене

Comment: @programmer403 почему бы вам не привести свое решение? Быть может, у вас получится лучше.